# How do I debug full project in PhpStorm via Xdebug - Magento 2

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, magento2, xdebug

I have setup Magento 2 on localhost.

PhpStorm project with Xdebug setup.

How do I debug full project? procedure and tips

Comment: Start here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: i know how to debug small program but don't know debug magento 2 project...